# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI :(

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my webApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiByActionWithid",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "" },
        constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" });

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiByAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "" });
```

The `changeOrderState` action looks like this:

```
public ResponseDTO ChangeOrderState(Int32 changeOrderState, string state) 
{ 
    IRestaurantManager rm = Core.CoreManager.Instance.GetService<IRestaurantManager>(); 
    return rm.ChangeOrderState(changeOrderState, state); 
}
```

And I call a method like this:

```
https://localhost:44302/api/Restaurant?changeOrderState=1&state=Rechazado
```

But it doesn't work, but in others calls that the same way do work

Comment: Can you paste Restaurant controller?

Comment: the function is :        public ResponseDTO ChangeOrderState(Int32 changeOrderState, string state)
        {
            IRestaurantManager rm = Core.CoreManager.Instance.GetService<IRestaurantManager>();
            return rm.ChangeOrderState(changeOrderState, state);
        }

Comment: and mu restaurant controller extends from a apiController

Comment: With no default actions specified, wouldn't the url be this:
api/Restaurant/ChangeOrderState?changeOrderState=1&state=Rechazado

Comment: i did this but doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

i solved this, the answer is add the next in te method [HttpGet] and my action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ResponseDTO ChangeOrderState(int changeOrderState, string state="")
    {
        IRestaurantManager rm = Core.CoreManager.Instance.GetService<IRestaurantManager>();
        return rm.ChangeOrderState(changeOrderState, state);
    }
```